# WPF control that fades out any overflowing text to transparent, rather than clipping it or wrapping?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

How can I create a WPF control (similar to a TextBlock) so that any overflowing text is faded out to transparent rather than simply clipping or wrapping?

I need to keep my control fixed-width, so expanding the width of the control to fit the text is not an option. I also do not want to make the text font smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, but I found the answer I needed on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/f8142d77-134c-4ebf-8ab4-f6c17955b218).

Comment: To clarify, you simply place a rectangle with a gradient brush on top of the TextBlock. In my case, the rectangle sits over the right hand edge of the text.

Comment: The problem with both your solutions (and it's my fault for not explaining it well enough) is that I needed the fade out part to be always on the right hand edge of the parent control. In this way, shorter strings in the textblock do not get their right hand edge faded out. I'm basically indicating 'there is more text than can be diplayed'. Anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you could do something like this:

```
    <TextBlock Text="Some long text here that should fade out">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.7" Color="Black"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>
```

But your control still needs to be wide enough to accommodate all the text for it to display.

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBlock Text="fgdfgfdgfddgfdgdfgfdgfdgd" Width="129" TextWrapping="NoWrap">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.661,0.399" StartPoint="0.008,0.496">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>                    
                <GradientStop Color="#7F000000" Offset="0.803"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#4C0A0909" Offset="0.95"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#BF000000" Offset="0.729"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#F8000000" Offset="0.699"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>
```

The trick on the gradient is that even though all colors are all based off black, The fade is achieved through opacity of each gradient by playing with A part of RGBA, in pseudo-code:

```
GradientStop Color="Black" A=100%               
GradientStop Color="Black" A=97%  Offset="0.803"
GradientStop Color="Black" A=75%  Offset="0.95"
GradientStop Color="Black" A=80%  Offset="0.729"
GradientStop Color="Black" A=30%  Offset="0.699"
```

Comment: I guess, Matt beat me to it, he's doing same thing a little bit differently. Either way works!